# Open jar file located at project/libraries

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar

I have a project named **Server1**. I need to call this project from another project named **7thSemProject**. I have added the class path of **Server1 ** in the project **7thSemProject** by right clicking on Libraries. Now how do I call this project.
My project structure looks like this:

Image :

[image]

Comment: Nootan , What do yo mean by calling project here? you want to access method/class of that project ?

Comment: @MayurBavisiya I want to execute jar file located at Libraries

Comment: Nootan , Still question is unclear to me sorry for that, If you want to execute jar file then simply you can execute via java -jar jarname.jar. 
But, It seems you are looking for something else.